# SQL use intermediate results

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column with numbers (float) that I would like to categorize and store a category as integer and as label (string). For now assume that the category is simply defined by the FLOOR(x).

This works:

```
SELECT salary,
  FLOOR(salary) AS category_integer,
  CASE WHEN FLOOR(salary) = 0
    THEN 'foo'
    ELSE 'bar'
  END AS category_label
FROM test01
```

but I was wondering if I could use the intermediate variable 'category_integer' defined in the beginning of my query in a later part, something like this:

```
SELECT salary,
  FLOOR(salary) AS category_integer,
  CASE WHEN category_integer = 0
    THEN 'foo'
    ELSE 'bar'
  END AS category_label
FROM test01
```

but this is apparently not how SQL works. I've looked into Common table Expressions but got lost there. Is there a way to reuse intermediate variables in an SQL expression?

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/aaffc/10)

I must have missed this but I couldn't find related questions so far.

Comment: postgreSQL, see tag (just added)

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.6.6 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9), 64-bit to be exact

Comment: would the answer be different for other RDBSMs?

Comment: For SQL Server I often use `CROSS APPLY` for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may resort to common table expressions - basically a query that produces a labelled result set you can refer to in subsequent queries.

Adapted to your example:

```
with cte as (
    select salary
         , floor(salary) as category_integer 
      from test01
)
SELECT salary
     , category_integer
     , CASE WHEN category_integer = 0
          THEN 'foo'
          ELSE 'bar'
       END AS category_label
 FROM cte
    ;
```

Consult the reference for more details: [CTE / `WITH` in pgSQL 9.6](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/queries-with.html).

See it at work in [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/aaffc/12).

Answer (score 1):

There are pre- and post-selection operations. For example `order by` and `group by` are post-selection instructions, `distinct` for example filters out duplicate results during the selection proces itself and as such duplicate results do not even enter the result set to be ordered or grouped.

When you use `AS`, you are telling PostgreSQL to take the result and put it in a column named `category_integer` in the output. You are not actually making a variable here that's available during query execution, as the result is only available after the query executes. As such, you can only do this with subselects where you have the result available as a virtual table in itself, where `category_integer` is a column in a table rather than a variable.

```
SELECT category_integer,
  CASE WHEN category_integer = 0
    THEN 'foo'
    ELSE 'bar'
  END AS category_label
FROM (SELECT FLOOR(0) AS category_integer FROM test01) AS test02
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-select-lists.html

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLE-ALIASES